# Haskell: Using a list to access indices

Tags: list, haskell

I am making a function that takes a boolean function and two lists. It needs to iterate through the first list and for the indices that make the boolean function true return the corresponding elements of the second list.

for example..

```
filterAB (>0) [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2] [5, 2, 5, 9, 0]
```

would return:

```
[9, 0]
```

I am using findIndices to return a list of the correct indices from the first list that make the boolean function true so that i can use them to access the elements of the second list. Here is my code so far:

```
filterAB boolFunc listA listB = take listC listB where
listC = findIndices boolFunc listA
```

Unfortunately the line

```
take listC listB
```

does not work because the take function requires type Int as a specifier while listC is type [Int]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I realize take would not be the right function anyway i would want something like listB !! listC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also using simple list comprehensions ...

```
[ghci] let filterAB f as bs = [ b | (a, b) <- zip as bs, f a]
[ghci] filterAB (>0) [-2,-1,0,1,2] [5,2,5,9,0]
[9,0]
[ghci]
```

Comment: I always forget to use list comprehensions, here it's definitly the shortest and more readable way to do it !

Comment: Thanks Luc. Am still new to Haskell List Comprehensions is something that is closest to Python that I normally use and so am generally drawn to them. The point-free notation still befuddles me :).

Answer (score 6):

An other version :

```
filterAB f l1 l2 = map snd $ filter (f . fst) $ zip l1 l2
```

If you have difficulties understanding the $, this version is the same :

```
let filterAB f l1 l2 = map snd ( filter (f . fst) ( zip l1 l2 ))
```

zip take two list and transform it one a list of tuple. For example :

```
zip [1,2,3,4] ["un", "deux", "trois", "quatre"] == [(1,"un"),(2,"deux"),(3,"trois"),(4,"quatre")]
```

filter take a list and a function that return true of false for each element of the list and filter it, it's like your filterAB but in simpler :

```
filter (>0) [-1, 2, -2, 3, -3] == [2,3]
```

fst take a couple and return the first element, so f . fst will apply f on the first element of your tuple. Like that filter (f . fst) allow use to filter on a list of tuple by just considering the first element of each tuple :

```
filter (odd . fst)  [(1,"un"),(2,"deux"),(3,"trois"),(4,"quatre")] == [(1,"un"),(3,"trois")]
```

If you don't get the dot, it's just function composition so the next two lines are identical :

```
h = f . g
h = f ( g x )
```

snd take a couple and return the second element. Using it with map allow us to take a list of tuple and return a list only of the second element of the tuple :

```
map snd [(1,"un"),(2,"deux"),(3,"trois"),(4,"quatre")] == ["un","deux","trois","quatre"]
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. I actually understand this one with the help of your explanation. I still need practice with pattern matching that the first solution implemented. I thought about using zip but i didn't know of the way to access individual elements of the couples. Thanks again to both of yall.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
filterAB f (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | f x = y : filterAB f xs ys
    | otherwise = filterAB f xs ys
filterAB _ _ _ = []
```

---

[Chapter 3. Defining Types, Streamlining Functions](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html) of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) given a very good explanation of the syntax involved here.

---

Testing:

```
*Main> filterAB (>0) [-2,-1,0,1,2] [5,2,5,9,0]
[9,0]
*Main> filterAB (>0) [-2,-1,0,1,2] [5,2,5,9]
[9]
*Main> filterAB (>0) [-2,-1,0,1,2] [5,2,5]
[]
*Main> filterAB (>0) [-2,-1,0] [5,2,5,9,0]
[]
*Main>
```

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not sure what that does and it doesnt compile.

Comment: Can you explain the syntax to me?

Comment: @Edge Could you tell me which part you do not understand?

Comment: Either way I appreciate your help

Comment: the colon operator in the parameters, the line characters at the beginning of the second and third lines, the colon on the second line, otherwise and the three underscores after the function call

Comment: @Edge Please check out this link: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching, you should read this if you want to understand better pattern matching. The all book is really good